# How to run Streamlit and Telegram Bot (python-telegram-bot) simultaneously?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, streamlit

I'm trying to run a Streamlit webpage and a python-telegram-bot instance together, because I need to call Telegram Bot functions from the Webpage.
Below is my code:

```
import streamlit as st
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CallbackContext, MessageHandler, Filters


def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.effective_chat.send_message(text="Hi")


def run_website():
    st.set_page_config(page_title="My Webpage", page_icon=":tada:", layout="wide")


def run_bot() -> None:
    updater = Updater('5222690292:AAHpTsw3ynWX0WA-2WonGErslqmoFjLHkvA')
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Add handlers
    echo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.all, echo)
    dispatcher.add_handler(echo_handler)

    # Start Bot
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_website()
    run_bot()
```

When starting the script with `streamlit run test.py`, I run into the following error:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter
```

I then tried removing `updater.idle()`, but got the following error:

```
telegram.error.Conflict: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
```

I also tried adding `@st.cache` to my `run_bot()` function to no avail (same error as above).